# Autogenerated keys in Pilog

Tags: lisp, prolog, picolisp

What's the best way to go about autogenerated keys for Pilog? i've
been digging around a bit and can't find anything related.

Hints and pointers would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the same behavior as auto increment in for instance MySQL with this
one: http://software-lab.de/doc/refG.html#genKey

I use it a lot in the VizReader code.

I'm not so sure I would've used it much though if I had know about the (id)
function from the start: http://software-lab.de/doc/refI.html#id

In my case it's all about displaying a nice id that is easy to relate for
humans and JavaScript in my non-traditional gui and as you can see both
approaches accomplish that but that latter is imo more elegant.

/Henrik Sarvell

<sup>(Copied verbatim form Henrik Sarvells' answer.)</sup>